# Charles Proxy not working on Mac with iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, macos, proxy, charles-proxy

I am trying the proxy the network traffic from my iPhone to Mac via Charles Proxy, below are the versions i am using:

- iPhone - model 13, OS - 15.4
- Mac - OS - Monterey (12.2.3)
- Charles - 4.6.2 (licensed)

I installed Charles on Mac, enabled SSL Proxying, added generic IP (0.0.0.0/0) in Access Control Settings, got the local IP address from Help and used it on my iPhone wifi settings - Proxy > manual > local IP from Charles and port 8888.

As soon as i do this my phone is not able to connect to internet at all. I have seen various instructions about adding root certificate, enabling trust settings etc, but those all can be done only if am able to connect to internet to download the certificates. Which i am unable to.

I went through every question on this site which mentions Charles proxy, but none could provide any solution to my problem so appreciate any inputs on this.

Comment: try to reset a phone; try proxyman;

Answer (score 1):

If there is no important information in your phone, you can reset the network settings first, then try the following

1. Make sure that both the computer and the phone are not using a virtual private network
2. The computer and the phone are in the same network environment
3. The computer has the Charles root certificate installed
4. The phone has successfully installed Charles' certificate and trusts it.

---

If the above suggestions don't help you, I suggest starting from scratch and troubleshooting the problem step by step
Let's take mobile phones and computers accessing https://www.google.com separately as an example

1. After the computer installs the certificate, can it be connected to the Internet normally, and can it crawl Google's response request?
2. The mobile phone and the computer are on the same network segment and use the proxy URL provided by charles. Can you access and download the certificate?
   [image]

3. On the computer, does Charles pop up an access prompt and ask you to choose whether to agree to the access?

4. Turn off the computer-side crawling and access it on the mobile phone to see if it can crawl the response request on the mobile phone.

Comment: I have reset network settings on the Mac, but havent tried doing it on the iPhone. Will give it a shot. I have ensured all other points you have mentioned. Those didnt help fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Next time, check the firewall in the security and privacy settings. It should not block Charles' incoming connections. I spent two hours trying to figure out what was going on